# is_tax query doesn't work with query string in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display specific content on taxonomy archive pages using the `is_tax` query below...

```
<?php if ( is_tax('category','subcategory') ) { ?>

<a href="?tag=10-off">10% off</a>

<?php } ?>
```

This content works fine when the URL is simply the taxonomy archive, but the moment a query string (such as the one in the content link) is applied to the taxonomy URL, the content no longer appears...

http://mywebsite.example/category/subcategory/?tag=10-off

Why is it that the query string is causing the `is_tax` query to fail?

Comment: What content? This question is just a snippet of something else.

Comment: This question belongs on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The "tag" keyword in query string is taking as a reserve word. Please change that to something else. It will start working.

NOTE : Tag is a reserve word for tag taxonomy.